# How to import npm javascript Priority Queue library when interviewing with coderpad

Tags: javascript, priority-queue

so Leetcode already supports @datastructures-js/priority-queue which is why I could just use

`let heap = new MinPriorityQueue()`  
out of the box. But then I realized when I interview with coderpad or hackerrank, I probably won't have access to the npm package I will need to use these datastructures out of the box like this.

Any advice on how I can make that happen?

I looked at coderpad documentation - and they say I can install any npm package I want, but so far have not found the right way to do it. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

https://coderpad.io/languages/frontend-frameworks/

> CoderPad supports npm command usage via the shell. This means that you can npm i any version of any library in the package ecosystem. You can also create an .npmrc file to customize the install logic of npm.

The shell seems to only be available in "frontend frameworks".

> When you select a frontend framework to code in, you’ll notice a multi-pane window that’s similar to what you’d find in popular IDEs.
>
> ... The third pane provides an interactive shell, server log output, and a console.

Picking **HTML** worked for me. It does give you a `main.js` file, although the regular output window is no longer and there is **Console** and **Logs** instead, so it's not quite as convenient as a straight javascript environment.

In **Shell**:

```
Starting shell...
~/app $ npm install --save @datastructures-js/priority-queue

added 2 packages, and audited 92 packages in 2s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

In `main.js`:

```
import {
  PriorityQueue,
  MinPriorityQueue,
  MaxPriorityQueue,
  ICompare,
  IGetCompareValue,
} from '@datastructures-js/priority-queue';

let heap = new MinPriorityQueue() 

console.log(heap)
```

Then click **Run** and check **Console** to see:

```
MinPriorityQueue {_heap: MinHeap, constructor: Object}
_heap: MinHeap
<constructor>: "MinPriorityQueue"
```